# OpenLDAP filter not returning empty OUs

Tags: ldap, openldap

I've tried the recommended filter as well as various variations and still, I cannot get a list of the OUs with no child entries.

```
Search Base: ou=compay,ou=drivers,dc=core,dc=com
Filter: (&(objectClass=organizationalUnit)(!(objectClass=*)))
```

Running LDAP version 3 of OpenLDAP.

Comment: `!(objectClass=*)` makes no sense whatsoever. Nothing can match it. I doubt you can accomplish this with a filter.

Comment: I agree but I am finding hundreds of posts, blogs, etc. that say this is they way.

Comment: Well they’re all wrong. Can you provide a link? I can't find any that say that, but I can find various other ways to do it.

Comment: Basically you will have to do a search for `(objectClass=organizationalUnit)` to find them all, then do a search based at each result item with `objectClass=*` and scope=subtree, and see which of those searches only returns 1 result, i.e. the organizational unit entry itself.

Comment: I found the solution, hasSubordinates=FALSE.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by using the following filter:

```
searchFilter = "(&(objectClass=organizationalUnit)(hasSubordinates=FALSE))"
```

So far it works great.